# StreamWriter generate IOException Unable to find the specified file

Tags: c#, ioexception

I have the following code:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
{
   writer.WriteLine(mydata);
}
```

that from time to time generate this error: `IOException.Message = "Unable to find the specified file"`.

The filename string is specified by the user and can be a network location like:

```
\\mycorp\Shared\Data.xml
```

And  `mydata` variable is a string too.

Is it possible that this code will generate a `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: Does the user that is running the code have write permissions for the network location? What is the exact exception message? Does the user type in the location or select it from a `FolderBrowserDialog` or alike? The network share should be `\\mycorp\Shared\Data` with two slashes.

Comment: The error is generated when the file cannot be found as the exception is stating. Did you check in advance with File.Exists? 
If it is a network path - perhaps no authorization? Or the network path cannot be reached currently? You could check in advance with Path.GetDirectoryName and Directory.Exists for the availability of the network path

Comment: I guess you need to use `UNC Path`

Comment: "Unable to find the specified file" it is exactly the error message.

Comment: Shared network address is correct, with two slashes, for some reason editor here each the second slash

Comment: from what I see, in the small sample you provided,  the filename is a directory and not a file.

Comment: thanks Sorceri, I corrected it. It was not a cause.

Comment: Which line is the exception coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question "Is it possible that this code will generate a `FileNotFoundException`?" is: No.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx

I suggest checking where the exception is coming from. It should give a line number in the exception stack trace.